# Cannot receive the email sent from the same domain using Apache James3.4

Tags: java, james

I installed Apache James 3.4(the latest version) in my windows system. I tested locally. So, I created two users, user1 and user2 in the localhost domain. And the two user address are `user1@localhost` and `user2@localhost`. Then, telnet the smtp port 25 using user1 and sent a message to user2. Telnet pop2 port 110 using user2, but the inbox is empty.
I tried to enable debug log and no any exception found. Here are the logs:

```
DEBUG 22:03:19,538 | org.apache.james.smtpserver.DataLineJamesMessageHookHandler | executing james message handler org.apache.james.protocols.smtp.core.esmtp.MailSizeEsmtpExtension@3fb1bbbc
DEBUG 22:03:19,539 | org.apache.james.smtpserver.DataLineJamesMessageHookHandler | executing hook org.apache.james.protocols.smtp.core.log.HookResultLogger@77894d86
DEBUG 22:03:19,539 | org.apache.james.smtpserver.DataLineJamesMessageHookHandler | executing hook org.apache.james.smtpserver.jmx.HookResultJMXMonitor@45d76490
DEBUG 22:03:19,540 | org.apache.james.smtpserver.DataLineJamesMessageHookHandler | executing james message handler org.apache.james.smtpserver.AddDefaultAttributesMessageHook@1c85f81
DEBUG 22:03:19,540 | org.apache.james.smtpserver.DataLineJamesMessageHookHandler | executing hook org.apache.james.protocols.smtp.core.log.HookResultLogger@77894d86
DEBUG 22:03:19,540 | org.apache.james.smtpserver.DataLineJamesMessageHookHandler | executing hook org.apache.james.smtpserver.jmx.HookResultJMXMonitor@45d76490
DEBUG 22:03:19,541 | org.apache.james.smtpserver.DataLineJamesMessageHookHandler | executing james message handler org.apache.james.smtpserver.SendMailHandler@57dc69c7
DEBUG 22:03:19,542 | org.apache.james.smtpserver.SendMailHandler | sending mail
INFO  22:03:19,549 | org.apache.james.smtpserver.SendMailHandler | Successfully spooled mail Mail1585836199538-6d97d1c0-d227-41fd-9d16-d608eeab8bc0 from MaybeSender{mailAddress=Optional[mailuser@localhost]} on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 for [user1@localhost]
DEBUG 22:03:19,550 | org.apache.james.smtpserver.DataLineJamesMessageHookHandler | executing hook org.apache.james.protocols.smtp.core.log.HookResultLogger@77894d86
DEBUG 22:03:19,550 | org.apache.james.smtpserver.DataLineJamesMessageHookHandler | executing hook org.apache.james.smtpserver.jmx.HookResultJMXMonitor@45d76490
DEBUG 22:03:19,552 | org.apache.james.mailetcontainer.impl.JamesMailSpooler | ==== Begin processing mail Mail1585836199538-6d97d1c0-d227-41fd-9d16-d608eeab8bc0 ====
DEBUG 22:03:19,555 | org.apache.james.mailetcontainer.lib.AbstractStateCompositeProcessor | Call MailProcessor root
DEBUG 22:03:19,581 | org.apache.james.mailetcontainer.impl.JamesMailSpooler | ==== End processing mail Mail1585836199538-6d97d1c0-d227-41fd-9d16-d608eeab8bc0 ====
```

Please help if you have any suggestion!!!